# seaborn joint plot, how to remove space between marginal axes

Tags: python, seaborn, axes, jointplot

I'm trying to plot a seaborn joint plot, but the axis lines are not connected. How can I connect the marginal axes back to the main plot?

```
sns_plot = sns.jointplot(x = 'f48', y= x,data=df, 
                     kind ='kde',
                     cmap = 'plasma')

sns_plot.set_axis_labels(xlabel = 'CD',ylabel = 'x position', size =14)
plt.suptitle('joint plot',y = 0.97, size =24) # title
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: note that "camp" should be "cmap"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) adds padding between the axes:

> `space` : Space between the joint and marginal axes (default 0.2)

Connect the marginal axes by setting `space=0`:

```
sns.jointplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', data=sns.load_dataset('iris'),
              kind='kde', cmap='plasma', space=0)
#                                        -------
```

[image]